# Unable to load stylesheet chrome extension manifest v3

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension and for some reason though I have set up my manifest in what I believe is the right way, I am unable to see my stylesheet loaded or applied

My manifest:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "version": "1.0",
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "storage",
        "webNavigation"
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        {
          "resources": [
            "my-styles.css",
            "myfont/myfont-Regular.ttf"
          ],
          "matches": [
            "https://my-site.com/*"
          ]
        }
      ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "https://my-site.com/*"
            ],
            "css" : ["my-styles.css"]
        }
    ]
}
```

project setup:

```
----
|-manifest.json
|-my-styles.css
|-myfont
    |-myfont-Regular.ttf
...
----
```

Does anyone know why this wouldn't be working?

Thanks

Comment: Fonts don't work through web_accessible_resources + file, IIRC, so try embedding it inside css as a data: url.